# Mail/mime.php failed to open stream

Tags: php

When I try to run this code:

```
require_once ("Mail.php");
require_once ("Mail/mime.php");

$text = "test";
$html_message = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>....</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>...</p>
</body>
</html>';

$headers["From"] = 'sample@sampel.com';
$headers["To"] = "sample@sampel.com"; 
$headers["Subject"] = "Sample SMTP PERL";
$headers["Content-Type"] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8';
$headers["Content-Transfer-Encoding"]= "8bit";

$mime = new Mail_mime; 
$mime->setTXTBody($text); 
$mime->setHTMLBody($html_message); 
$mimeparams=array(); 

// It refused to change to UTF-8 even if the header was set to this, after adding the following lines it worked.

$mimeparams['text_encoding']="8bit"; 
$mimeparams['text_charset']="UTF-8"; 
$mimeparams['html_charset']="UTF-8"; 
$mimeparams['head_charset']="UTF-8"; 

$mimeparams["debug"] = "True"; 

$body = $mime->get($mimeparams); 
$headers = $mime->headers($headers); 
$page_content = "Mail now."; 

// SMTP server name, port, user/passwd 
$smtpinfo["host"] = "xxx;
$smtpinfo["port"] = "465";
$smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
$smtpinfo["username"] = "sample@sample.com";
$smtpinfo["password"] = "xxx";
$smtpinfo["debug"] = "True"; 


// Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
$mail=& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);

$mail->send($to, $headers, $body));
```

I got this error message:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(Mail/mime.php): failed to open stream: No
such file or directory in /home3/xxx/public_html/xxx/zzz/ccc/vvv.php
on line 203 

PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
'Mail/mime.php'

(include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear:/usr/lib/php/PEAR')
in /home3/xxx/public_html/xxx/zzz/ccc/vvv.php on line 203
```

And I don't know how to fix that. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is php, not Perl.  If you fed this through a perl interpreter, you'd get all sorts of errors very different from what you're getting.  (Sorry if that sounds mean... I intend it to be informative.)

Second, the error message is very helpful.  It says what's allowed and what's not with the

> (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear:/usr/lib/php/PEAR')

Typically, this is because of an invalid path, or filesystem permissions.

To rule out filesystem permissions being the culprit, you can check that everyone is allowed to read the file (`cd path/to/Mail; chmod a+r mime.php` in linux).  If "the user who runs the web server" (typically an unprivileged user) can not read the file (or does not have execute permissions on the Mail folder, which can be granted with `cd path/to/Mail; cd ..; chmod a+x Mail`) then the file Mail/mime.php can not be imported (or required).  Depending on the environment, filesystem permissions can cause these issues (wonky web host configuration, roll-your-own while using the default `umask` on many linux distros, etc).  It's a first place to look.  The execute permissions are not only necessary on that folder, but everywhere up the filesystem tree.

Your include_path tells you where it looks for files.  The '.' at the beginning says "the current directory".  It's possible that the Mail.php not throwing an error is because there's some Mail.php available, other than the one you think.

Many people suggest always using absolute paths instead of relative paths (like your require_once does), to try to avoid surprises and unexpected behavior.

This depends very much on where the Mail.php and Mail/mime.php are in the directory structure relative to where your php script is.  The parent folder of your php script is '.'.  You need to make sure that the path to the Mail.php and Mail/mime.php are relative to that. For instance, if you had:

```
/path/to/my/web/stuff/admin/this.php
/path/to/my/web/stuff/Mail.php
/path/to/my/web/stuff/Mail/mime.php
```

In the this.php, you would have to refer to '../Mail.php' and '../Mail/mime.php' for your require_once statements because those files live up one directory from where this.php lives.

Basically, without information about file permissions and directory structure, there's little we can offer.  I hope this overview of common issues is helpful.  If you can update your question to include information about the directory structure and an affirmation that permissions are correct, others may be able to help you resolve this.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have installed the needed PEAR packages.

Mail.php is part of "Mail", but mime.php is part of "Mail_Mime".

```
pear install Mail Mail_Mime
```

Comment: It works for me Thank you so much @matthew wilcoxson. You save the day!

Answer (score -1):

This screenshot is for those who use XAMPP, and want to include Mail_Mime or Mail to your environment.

To find out how to install Mail for XAMPP following my post here [PHP Warning: require(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962278/php-warning-requiremail-php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

[image: This screenshot is for those who use XAMPP, and want to include Mail_Mime or Mail to your environment]